# How to retrieve sign of the inequality in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Say I have an inequality like

```
ineq = a < b;
```

and a set of equalities of the form

```
eq = a == c;
...
```

Now, my aim is to use the set of equalities and transform them into an inequality based on the sign in 'ineq'. So if 'ineq' has '<', I want to obtain

```
a < Min[b, c, ...]
```

However, if 'ineq' has '>', I want to obtain

```
a > Max[b, c, ...].
```

How can I retrieve the sign (less/greater) in 'ineq'? Also, assume that I always have 'a' to be explicitly on the left side of the sign.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use [Sign](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sign.html)?

Comment: I'm not very sure what you are really trying to do.  But try executing the snippet `FullForm[ineq]` or `FullForm[b==c]` to see how *Mathematica* represents those expressions.  That should give you some ideas on how to manipulate them.